# Time for international-international transfer in Ataturk airport

Tags: transit, turkey, isl

How long does a transfer from airplane to gate take in Ataturk airport in Turkey? International to international? Do we go through customs or what?

Comment: Can you provide more details, what passport you're on, airline and so on? How long do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on different things. Ataturk airport is quite busy, so you will spend some time on the queues. If I understood your question right, you will have a transit at Ataturk. the queue will be on the luggage security control and it will approximately take 20 mins. The total time from gate to gate will approximately be 40-45 mins.

Comment: But my luggage will just be loaded on my next airplane ? (flying one ticket/airline) Brussels>Istanbul>Manila. I thought there is no security.. You just go off the plane and proceed direct to the gate for your next flight?

Comment: I mean your handbag security. But since you are landing from Brussels (an EU country), then guess you dont need to pass through the security control. you will just go directly to the next gate and it will go faster for you.